# C# - Read json to subclass fields

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to make a `Config.cs` class to use on my project.

Structure is supposed to consist of categories of settings. For example, `Config.LogOnDetails` should hold the values for MySQL login.

Here is my current structure.

```
public class Config
    {
        public string pPath;
        public string configPath;
        public string configFilePath;

        public class LogOnDetails
        {
            public string MySQLDatabaseName { get; set; }
            public string MySQLUser { get; set; }
            public string MySQLPassword { get; set; }
            public string MySQLAddress { get; set; }
        }

        public Config()
        {
            pPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            configPath = Path.Combine(pPath, @"/config");
            configFilePath = Path.Combine(configPath, "/config.json");
            //If it doesn't exist, create a directory for the configuration to be stored in
            if (!Directory.Exists(configPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("config");
            }
            if (!File.Exists(configFilePath))
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
                File.WriteAllText(configFilePath, json);
                Console.WriteLine("Created a new blank config file!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is how I'm trying to load the config to the class.

```
 //Initialize configuration
 Config.LogOnDetails logOnDetails = new Config.LogOnDetails();

 //Load config from json
 config.LogOnDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config.LogOnDetails>(config.configFilePath);
```

But this doesn't seem to work and looks like I don't understand subclasses properly. How can I organize my class so it will work?

json example:

```
{
    "pPath": null,
    "configPath": null,
    "configFilePath": null,
    "MySQLDatabaseName": null,
    "MySQLUser": null,
    "MySQLPassword": null,
    "MySQLAddress": null
}
```

Comment: Yup, pressed enter accidentally and posted. I've updated with the question now.

Comment: Please include an example of what your JSON looks like (remember to anonymize any passwords!)

Comment: For the loading on the the last line, did you mean to write config.LogOnDetails? or just logOnDetails. You can't deserialize to a class definition, only an instance. Also I'm pretty sure that DeserializeObject doas not read from the file for you, you need to do that.

Comment: @Jamiec Added it.

Comment: Im a little confused is it *just* the `MySql*` data you want to store, or is there fields in `Config` you want to store as well? You seem to be mixing up the location of your configuration with the things you want to configure

Comment: doing this in the constructor is also confusing me

Comment: The stuff in the ctor is *clearly* wrong - separation of concerns and all that!

Comment: @mikelegg Yes, it's supposed to have a logOnDetails there so it deserializes to an instance. And I updated the file to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config.LogOndetails>(File.ReadAllText(@"config/config.json"));`

Comment: @Jamiec I can try rewriting it in another way, I just wanted it to automatically deserialize the json to itself when instantiated. If you have tips how to point me in the right direction I could do that :)

Comment: @Jamiec Also about your previous question. I want the `Config.LogOnDetails` subclass to contain the data for MySQL login, I could have another subclass (for example) `Config.Settings` which could contain fields like `Config.Settings.Locale`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'm going to start with a general point. The `Config` class should know nothing about how it is stored, or where it is stored. That is a completely separate "concern". See [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

---

Start off with the definition of what you want to store. That seems to be your MySql info, and some other info. These should all be individual classes (To be clear, you can nest them, but there is no need to and complicates the answer a little):

```
 public class LogOnDetails
 {
        public string MySQLDatabaseName { get; set; }
        public string MySQLUser { get; set; }
        public string MySQLPassword { get; set; }
        public string MySQLAddress { get; set; }
 }
```

You can have another one:

```
public class Settings 
{
     public string Locale { get; set; }
}
```

And you can compose these into a master config object

```
public class Config 
{
     public string SomeTopLevelProp {get; set; }
     public LogOnDetails LogOnDetails { get; set; }
     public Settings Settings  { get; set; }
}
```

The way to serialize and deserialize this is fairly straightforward

```
var config = new Config() 
{
   SomeTopLevelProp = "ABCDEF",
   LogOnDetails = new LogOnDetails()
   {
       MySqlDatabaseName = "Foo"  ,
       MySQLUser = "MyUser"
       // snip the rest of the props
   },
    Settings = new Settings
    {
        Locale = "en-GB"
    }
}
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(config );

var mySettingDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Config>(json);
```

I have purposely left out the writing to a file part - you seem to know how to do that - but keep it *outside* of the `Config` class. For example a separate classes, perhaps just with 2 static methods which knows how/where to store the config

```
public static class ConfigLoader
{
     public static void StoreConfig(Config config, string location) {... }
     public static Config LoadConfig(string location) {... }
}
```

---

A note on security - storing your database password as plain text in a json config file is generally a bad idea. You might consider encrypting it, and storing that and decrypting it when using the value.

Comment: just about to post exactly the same. Only other point I would make .... if this is data you care about (i.e. not a hobby / student project) then you better figure out a way to encrypt those login details.

Comment: @Jamiec Thank you so much! That's a great solution, and I will read more on SoC.

Comment: @mikelegg I will eventually add encryption mechanism to the configuration, I just wanna get the base functionality working first since the data we're storing in MySQL is freely available. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Jamiec One more question. In other classes I wanna access `Config.LogOnDetails.MySQLUser` but that's gonna fill up a lot of rows quickly.

This is how I'm loading it. 

            `Config config = new Config();       
            ConfigLoader.Load(config);
            Config.LogOnDetails logOnDetails = new Config.LogOnDetails();`

However that doesn't seem to work. How can I assign LogOnDetails instance so I can just do `logOnDetails.MySQLUser?`

Comment: @Tatu you're mixing up the class definitions and the *instances*. If you look at my `Load` method it took the *path to the json* and not the `Config` class. So you would access it by first doing `Config config = ConfigLoader.Load("some/path/config.json")` then `var user = config.LogOnDetails.MySqlUser`.